# Have main content background color expend all the way down to footer at bottom of browser

Tags: html, css, background, sticky-footer

Here is my current HTML and CSS http://jsfiddle.net/fqu6U/

I want the red to go all the way to the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://jsfiddle.net/fqu6U/3/

Problems that were interfering: float, height: auto.

Comment: I just see a big red block (no footer) in IE8

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add this to the bottom of the css:

```
body
{
    background-color:red
}
```

EDIT: Given your comment you might want to look at this: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

Comment: because i need the top to be transparent and only the content are to be red. not the whole body bg